# Jquery Backbone.View.extend function call

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

i want to asking about what is directory.views.SearchPage for? can i call this function as above? is possibe to call page load?

```
directory.views.SearchPage = Backbone.View.extend({

templateLoader: directory.utils.templateLoader,
EmployeeListView: directory.views.EmployeeListView,

initialize: function() {
  this.template = _.template(this.templateLoader.get('search-page'));
},

render: function(eventName) {
  $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
  this.listView = new directory.views.EmployeeListView({el: $('ul', this.el), model:this.model});
  this.listView.render();
  return this;
},
events: {
  "keyup .search-key": "search"
},
// Start the search function
search: function(event) {
  var key = $('.search-key').val();
  this.model.findByName(key);
}
});
```

Comment: Uhm, yours seems a correct approach. Can you make the question more understandable?

Comment: Sorry, actaully i want page load run this search: function(event), i code a events page "ready" and "load", but no trigger when page loaded...

i have a question how to make page load run this function? or how to call this search: function(event) in out side function?

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you want to initialize, render and then call the "share" function on your main view class on page load. Since jQuery is available, i would go simply with:

```
var searchPage = new directory.views.SearchPage();
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    searchPage.render();
    searchPage.search(e);
});
```

But please note that:

- I don't see a reason to pass the event argument from $(document).ready, or at least it's not used at all in your code
- my answer is pretty generic, since the question is generic (it gets down to "how I call a function on page load?")
- What you define using Backbone.View.extend is somewhat similar to a classic prototype (not really, but gives you an idea). Therefore, you should then instantiate a new instance from this extended "class" before accessing its methods and properties.

Comment: hi sixFingers, i try your code, but not take effect, even can't alert there, is var searchPage = new directory.views.SearchPage(); ok?

Comment: @user2453923: The example provided by sixFingers is fine. Are you sure that no errors are occurring when you intialize the view? Have you checked the browser console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined in underscore-min.js

Comment: So you need to look at the call stack for your error and find out which line in the directory.views.SearchPage the error is occurring on.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of    undefined     
     underscore-min.js:29
     b.template underscore-min.js:29
     directory.views.SearchPage.Backbone.View.extend.initialize app.js:904
     g.View backbone-min.js:33
     d backbone-min.js:38
     (anonymous function)

should i using console.log() to check the error? i am very beingger there...